# Issue with sendrawtransaction missing inputs error code -25

Tags: bitcoin-core

Working with Bitcoin-qt 0.16.3 testnet

Attempting to `sendrawtransaction`, however, receive following error:

```
Missing inputs (code -25)
```

From what I have read, this results from attempting to use outputs in the transaction that have already been spent.

I am confused, however, because I am explicitly using a transaction listed by `listunspent`. Doesn't that mean the output is unspent???

If you could point me to where I am going wrong, it would be greatly appreciated.

Here's exactly my work:

`listunspent`

output

```
[
  {
    "txid": "8d42a2db310b794ae0d75ed9a68262081fd83817a862f87a99cd176ce8743223",
    "vout": 1,
    "address": "2MtBLx3arsHFV1cBYSo5AXmX5Pf3tfcgda3",
    "account": "addy2",
    "redeemScript": "0014436faf386d5c77c575e3372a97e268a08e3f5378",
    "scriptPubKey": "a9140a3c45e4e27e98b6bf1171b4fe1bf689b9a3dbf287",
    "amount": 0.00010000,
    "confirmations": 229,
    "spendable": true,
    "solvable": true,
    "safe": true
  }
]
```

input

```
createrawtransaction '[{ "txid": "8d42a2db310b794ae0d75ed9a68262081fd83817a862f87a99cd176ce8743223", "vout":2 }]' '{ "2N8kPhdhwAYYK8rFt7Fhvm3oapsMF7vqbcB":0.00003, "2MtBLx3arsHFV1cBYSo5AXmX5Pf3tfcgda3":0.0000695}'
```

output

```
0200000001233274e86c17cd997af862a81738d81f086282a6d95ed7e04a790b31dba2428d0200000000ffffffff02b80b00000000000017a914aa0e0ebe49d03dc1b79f91775aada9293179bb2387261b00000000000017a9140a3c45e4e27e98b6bf1171b4fe1bf689b9a3dbf28700000000
```

input

```
signrawtransaction '0200000001233274e86c17cd997af862a81738d81f086282a6d95ed7e04a790b31dba2428d0200000000ffffffff02b80b00000000000017a914aa0e0ebe49d03dc1b79f91775aada9293179bb2387261b00000000000017a9140a3c45e4e27e98b6bf1171b4fe1bf689b9a3dbf28700000000' '[{"txid":"8d42a2db310b794ae0d75ed9a68262081fd83817a862f87a99cd176ce8743223","vout":2,"scriptPubKey":"a9140a3c45e4e27e98b6bf1171b4fe1bf689b9a3dbf287","redeemScript": "0014436faf386d5c77c575e3372a97e268a08e3f5378",
"amount":0.0001}]'
```

output

```
{
  "hex": "02000000000101233274e86c17cd997af862a81738d81f086282a6d95ed7e04a790b31dba2428d0200000017160014436faf386d5c77c575e3372a97e268a08e3f5378ffffffff02b80b00000000000017a914aa0e0ebe49d03dc1b79f91775aada9293179bb2387261b00000000000017a9140a3c45e4e27e98b6bf1171b4fe1bf689b9a3dbf287024830450221009274a153ee55925681d5382fecbff723e2ec12e92dafc7188565e2ee2bef092402201133ec3545333afeacda23b63917660ed62be667508dbb5a121a4ed9aa52125401210273340ff4511f6bbcf7d9f1c1fe69f66704398e54f4cde0e0ec60313476fc92ab00000000",
  "complete": true
}
```

input

```
sendrawtransaction 02000000000101233274e86c17cd997af862a81738d81f086282a6d95ed7e04a790b31dba2428d0200000017160014436faf386d5c77c575e3372a97e268a08e3f5378ffffffff02b80b00000000000017a914aa0e0ebe49d03dc1b79f91775aada9293179bb2387261b00000000000017a9140a3c45e4e27e98b6bf1171b4fe1bf689b9a3dbf287024830450221009274a153ee55925681d5382fecbff723e2ec12e92dafc7188565e2ee2bef092402201133ec3545333afeacda23b63917660ed62be667508dbb5a121a4ed9aa52125401210273340ff4511f6bbcf7d9f1c1fe69f66704398e54f4cde0e0ec60313476fc92ab00000000
```

output

```
Missing inputs (code -25)
```

Answer (score 1):

From your `listunspent`: **`"vout": 1,`**

From your `createrawtransaction`: **`"vout":2`**

You are trying to spend an output that doesn't exist.

Comment: negative. if i amend `createnewtransaction` so `"vout":1` and repeat process, I still get same error.

Comment: Did you also change the `vout` parameter in `signrawtransaction` too?